# Get Month and YTD Level Share ( both Value , Volume) .Share formula - Comp / Industry

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have 2 tables

table1 :company - it contains details of ytd which is running total of mtd and details grouped at company level

```
Company Month   Year    MTD             YTD
CompA   January 2018    1796931.7382390 1796931.7382390
CompA   February2018    1721060.8847610 3517992.6230000
CompA   March   2018    1616111.8761772 5134104.4991772
CompB   January 2018    1694819.2451073 1694819.2451073
CompB   February2018    1792263.2771860 3487082.5222933
CompB   March   2018    1630935.4786730 5118018.0009663
```

query for table 1:

```
select Company,
DATENAME(MONTH,Period) as Month,
year(period) as Year,
sum(sales) as MTD,
sum(Sum(sales)) over (partition by company ,year(period) order by month(period)) as YTD
from sqltest 
where DATENAME(MONTH,Period) in ('January', 'February', 'March')
group by company,DATENAME(MONTH,Period),month(period),year(period)
order by company,month(period),year(period)
```

table 2 : group - it contains same date and detail as above but all companies are grouped as industry
to get mtd and ytd

```
Company     Month   year    mtd              ytd
Industry    January 2018    6783246.5381293 6783246.5381293
Industry    February2018    6504651.9038856 13287898.4420149
Industry    March   2018    6387423.7180942 19675322.1601091
Industry    April   2018    6799821.3940993 26475143.5542084
Industry    May     2018    1755647.7008300 28230791.2550384
Industry    June    2018    1755898.5033900 29986689.7584284
Industry    July    2018    1713669.1531610 31700358.9115894
```

now i want to get share for each month for ytd and mtd

```
desired o/p:
company    year  month    ytd share                              mtd share 
company a  2018  january  <ytd share of comp a for jan month>    <mtd share of comp a for jan month>
company a  2018  februray <ytd share of comp a for feb month>    <mtd share of comp a for feb month>
```

and so on ...

i want to calculate mtd and ytd level share month wise for each company.

Share formula  - Comp / Industry.

Answer (score 0):

You could just `join` the results or your existing query with the new table:

```
select
    t1.company,
    t1.yr,
    t1.mn,
    t1.mtd / t2.mtd mtd_share,
    t1.ytd / t2.ytd ytd_share
from (
    select
        company,
        year(period) yr,
        month(period) mn,
        sum(sales) mtd,
        sum(sum(sales)) over(partition by company, year(period) order by month(period)) ytd
    from tablea
    group by 
        company,
        year(period),
        month(period)
) t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.yr = t1.yr and t2.mn = t1.mn
order by 
    t1.company,
    t1.yr,
    t1.mn
```

Comment: it is giving error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @Adi: please share the error message or problem that you are having...